# What is the purpose of set here?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class person
{
private: 
string name;
int birth_year;
char sex;
public:
person()
{ 
    string name; cout<<"Name: "; cin>>name; set_name(name);
    int birth_year; cout<<"Birth year: "; cin>>birth_year; set_birth_year(birth_year);
    char sex; cout<<"Sex: "; cin>>sex; set_sex(sex); 
}
~person() { }
```

what does `set_name(name)` do here?

Comment: It's not `std::set` (or any other `set` data structure) referenced here, it's part of a name of the functions, to set the name (I guess) and sex of the person. If you look further down in the class I can bet you will find those functions there. Do a search for the setter and getter pattern.

Comment: It describes a method to change a variable. For example, if you wanted to put 2 extra wheels on your bike, you'd follow a method to achieve that, you wouldn't just magically declare you now have a 4 wheel bike. The new value is a result of some actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `set_nume` is a member function of the class that sets data member `nume` of the class (of an object of the class) to the value of local variable `nume`(that is entered by the user) passed as an argument of the function. Maybe this member function does some checks of the validaty of nume. For example the function could convert the first letter of nume to upper case and all other letters to lower case and so on. You should look through the function that to see what it does (it can simply set data member `nume` to argument `nume`  like this->nume = nume). Usually such member functions are called as setters. They have the public access control and allow to set private data members of a class.